# how to generate Coverage.profdata on Xcode

Tags: code-coverage, xcode9.2, slather

first of all thank you in advance for helping me figure this out. 
I recently try using slather to produce a code coverage report for my xcode project, but when i execute slather it fail with error below

> Are you sure your project is generating coverage? Make sure you enable code coverage in the Test section of your Xcode scheme.
>       Did you specify your Xcode scheme? (--scheme or 'scheme' in .slather.yml)
>       If you're using a workspace, did you specify it? (--workspace or 'workspace' in .slather.yml)
>       If you use a different Xcode configuration, did you specify it? (--configuration or 'configuration' in .slather.yml)

even though i already specify all configuration mention above in .slather.yml file. But i'm still getting the same error. Below are my .slather.yml code

```
output_directory: slather-report
scheme: *Project scheme* // This scheme has enabled code coverage in test section 
workspace: *Project*.xcworkspace 
xcodeproj: *Project*.xcodeproj 
configuration: Staging 
arch: x86_64 
html: true 
ignore: 
- Pods/*
```

so i go through the slather `project.rb` file and find out that slather try to find a file called `Coverage.profdata`. But upon executing Xcode unitTest, Xocde never generate any file with name `Coverage.profdata`, Even though i already enable code coverage on that particular scheme.

So, am i missing something on generating `Coverage.profdata`, if yes please let me know? Thank you again in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Coverage.profdata file is usually present in the Build/Intermediate/{scheme}/ProfileData directory. Make sure that the file is present there.

Also, make sure you are using the Product->Test option to generate the Coverage.profdata file as simply running the target in Release/Debug mode will not generate the code coverage data.